# ¿Por qué se usa la forma "tú" en publicidades en vez de "usted"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, pronombres, formalidad, tiempos-verbales

Muchas veces he encontrado publicidades que usan la forma *tú* como lo siguiente:

[image]

Yo pienso que que estaría mejor usar la forma *usted*, porque es mas formal y profesional (en mi opinión).

¿Quizás no pienso correctamente? ¿Qué significa la forma *tú*?

Comment: Y en la Argentina, las encontrarás usando el *vos* como «¿Nos conocés? … Protegé a los manatís. Visitá … » :)  (por cierto, en tu pregunta, debe ser *pienso que **sería** mejor*)

Comment: @guifa Mirá vos: **manatís**. Hubiera jurado que la única forma aceptada es "manatíes". Todoj loj diaj se aprende algo nuevo.

Comment: @belisarius : las palabras que acaban en los monoptongos *-í* o *-ú* siempre admiten dos formas plurales, o *-s* o *-es*. Con gentilicios es más común con *-es*, con palabras importadas como *champú* es más normal con *-s* (en ambos casos son aceptables ambas formas). Con las demás palabras, la diferencia principal es que *-es* suele pertenecer más al habla culta.

Comment: Great question! I found some interesting resources: [El usted agoniza](http://www.lavanguardia.com/estilos-de-vida/20121102/54354733397/el-usted-agoniza.html), [El uso de tuteo y de trato de usted en la publicidad periodística de hoy y hace 25 años](http://is.muni.cz/th/146604/ff_b/Las_formas_de_tratamiento.pdf), [Tú y usted como estrategias de estilo y persuasión en la comunicación publicitaria](http://www.um.es/tonosdigital/znum18/secciones/estudio-1-tu_y_usted.htm)

Comment: Creo que se debe considerar además que la publicidad puede estar dirigida a todo tipo de edades: adultos, jóvenes y niños. El uso de "usted" puede encasillar a un público más adulto, aunque en algunas zonas de Colombia y Centro América se usa para todos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Puede ser para ofrecer cercanía con el publico al que se dirige. La forma *usted* es mucho mas formal y desde luego implica respeto, pero eso no quiere decir que la forma *tú* carezca de él. Creo que en este caso hay mucho contexto en el canal.

Puedo decirte, como nativo hispanohablante, que *usted* puede tener connotaciones negativas. Cuando yo tenía alrededor de veintipocos años, si mis profesores de universidad se dirigían a mí *de usted* lo interpretaba como parte del ambiente serio de la clase o del profesor. Si alguien se dirigía a mí *de usted* en la calle al preguntarme la hora, me hacia sentir **muy viejo**.

La publicidad puede querer apartarse de esas connotaciones de **demasiado** serio, demasiado formal o "envejecer" al interlocutor. No necesariamente falta al respeto. Si ese cartel es de un zoo, el publicista lo querrá asociar con algo lúdico, no con algo serio y formal.

Answer (score 7):

En efecto, el uso de *usted* es más formal, pero no necesariamente más profesional.

En América, algunas regiones al menos, desde la segunda mitad del siglo XX si no es que desde antes, el uso de deícticos sociales para marcar respeto o cortesía, concretamente la forma *usted* ha ido en retroceso en su uso.

Anteriormente era habitual que los hijos se dirigieran *de usted* a los padres. Ni qué decir con desconocidos o las figuras de autoridad: el cura, el maestro, etc. Ahora se considera excesivo y anticuado. Sin embargo, entre los ancianos y en zonas rurales suele usarse todavía.

El uso del pronombre *tú* ha servido para romper esa distancia, esa lejanía que las jerarquías sociales marcaban antaño. Se usa como símbolo de confianza, de amistad incluso. El cartel que mencionas, como dice Diego, pretende ser lúdico, no serio, yo agregaría que incluso amigable.

Por otro lado, también es cierta esa connotación negativa que puede usarse con el pronombre *usted*, que puede usarse como ya dijo **Diego**. En mi experiencia breve y reciente con una colombiana, usa el pronombre *usted* cuando está molesta, para marcar distancia.

Así que como puedes ver, usar *usted* no es necesariamente profesional, tiene muchos matices.

Una última aclaración en cuanto a la nota de **guifa**. En ciertas regiones de América, notoriamente en Argentina y Uruguay, pero también en regiones fronterizas de Paraguay y Bolivia con Argentina. De igual modo que en la región paisa de Colombia (departamentos de Antioquia, Caldas, Risaralda y Quindío), y en Centroamérica, se usa el *voseo*. Se dice que incluso en el sureste de mi país (México) pero no lo he escuchado.

Este fenómeno implica la sustitución del pronombre *tú* por *vos* y el uso de formas verbales *átonas*. Es bastante interesante el voseo, pero no me quiero entretener con él. En todo caso, en la Wikipedia hay [un artículo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo) bastante extenso al respecto. Puedes leerlo si te interesa. El punto con todo esto es que si el cartel que muestras estuviese dirigido al publico argentino o uruguayo, entonces en vez de usar *usted* se usaría el *vos* con las mismas intenciones.

Comment: Qué simpática esa anécdota sobre la colombiana que, molesta, usa _usted_ para marcar distancia. Yo el otro día hablaba con una pareja de colombianos y me confesaban que después de dos años de novios decidieron empezar a tutearse... Me explicaban que incluso entre familiares directos, si el vínculo no era muy fuerte o no había suficiente confianza, se trataban _de usted_.

Comment: En efecto, y dado que apenas estabamos saliendo, si yo llegaba tarde o ahcía o decía algo que no fuera de su agrado usaba dicho pronombre para _pintar su raya_, o sea distanciarse. Es un tipo de deixis social.

Answer (score 4):

As a native speaker of English, my take on this is that, especially in advertising, the company wants to make a connection with the intended audience, and therefore will use either the formal or the informal to connect with either a older vs. younger, more hip/modern vs. traditional, or formal vs. familiar crowd.  In the case of the post above, the intention seems to be to make the reader feel part of the family, that we all must do it together or maybe even as far as implying that the future generations of manatee are as important as our own children.  If you look in any Spanish-language magazine with a lot of ads (not hard to find), you get a sense of this from the formal vs the informal commands used to sell the product.